# "No test methods found in the Apex code included in the package." But coverage is at 100%?

Tags: lightning-web-components, code-coverage, package

I have created a LWC component, it has 1 Apex class that is test covered at 100%. However when I try to create my package, it fails saying "*No test methods found in the Apex code included in the package. At least 75% test coverage is required.*" for my class.

When I run `sf apex run test --wait 100 --code-coverage` I get `ComunikAppletApexClass    100%`, `ComunikAppletApexClass` being the Apex class from my component.

Here's my test class, it is contained in a file located in the same folder as my Apex class.

```
@isTest
private class TestComunikAppletApexClass {
    @isTest static void testCreateCallLog() {
        Account acct = new Account(Name='Test Account');
        insert acct;
        
        Contact contact = new Contact(LastName='Test Contact', AccountId=acct.Id);
        insert contact;
        
        Task callLogReturned = ComunikAppletApexClass.createCallLog(contact, 'test', 'Outbound', 'http://test.url/');
        
        Task callLog = [
            SELECT 
                Id, WhoId, Description, Priority, Status, Subject, CallType, Type, TaskSubtype
            FROM Task 
            WHERE Id = :callLogReturned.Id
        ];
        System.assertEquals(callLog.WhoId, contact.Id);
        System.assertEquals(callLog.Description, 'http://test.url/');
        System.assertEquals(callLog.Priority, 'Normal');
        System.assertEquals(callLog.Status, 'Completed');
        System.assertEquals(callLog.Subject, 'test');
        System.assertEquals(callLog.CallType, 'Outbound');
        System.assertEquals(callLog.Type, 'Call');
        System.assertEquals(callLog.TaskSubtype, 'Call');
    }

    @isTest static void testGetContactByPhoneNumber() {
        Account acct = new Account(Name='Test Account');
        insert acct;
        
        Contact contact = new Contact(LastName='Test Contact', AccountId=acct.Id, Phone='1234567890');
        insert contact;
        
        Contact contactReturned = ComunikAppletApexClass.getContactByPhoneNumber('1234567890');
        
        System.assertEquals(contactReturned.Id, contact.Id);
    }

    private static final String FAKE_RESPONSE_JSON = '{"status": "ok"}';

    private class Mock implements HttpCalloutMock {
        public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
            HTTPResponse res = new HTTPResponse();
            res.setBody(FAKE_RESPONSE_JSON);
            res.setStatusCode(200);
            return res;
        }
    }

    @isTest static void testLoginUser() {
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Mock());

        Test.startTest();
        String responseJSON = ComunikAppletApexClass.loginUser('test@example.com', 'test');
        Test.stopTest();

        System.assertEquals(FAKE_RESPONSE_JSON, responseJSON);
    }
}
```

I feel like I am doing something wrong but I don't understand what.

Comment: did you added test class also in package?

Comment: @ManjotSingh ok yeah, for some reason the only thing not automatically added to the package when I added my component was the test class. Is this normal?

Comment: If this is a 1GP package that is normal. For a 2GP, just being in the same packageDirectory means it is packaged (unless you have some .forceignore setup).

Answer (score 1):

For a 1GP package you must explicitly add unit test classes (and the Apex classes, unless they are a dependency for one or more class already in the package). You do this in the Package Manager in Setup on the packaging org.

For a 2GP, just being in the same `packageDirectory` means it is packaged (unless you have some `.forceignore` setup).